# Is it possible to raise a custom exception from assert method?

Tags: java, assert

I have to validate a request with around of 40 fields that needs to be mandatory.

I would like to do this by avoiding the classic `if (field1 == null) throw new XXException("msg");`

For example I have the following code:

```
if (caller == null)
{
    // Caller cannot be empty
    throw new CallerErrorException(new CallerError("", "incorrect caller"));
}
if (person == null)
{
    // Person cannot be empty
    throw new PersonErrorException(new CustomerError("", "incorrect customer"));
}
if (module == null)
{
    // Module cannot be empty
    throw new ModuleErrorException(new ModuleError("", "module must be X"));
}
```

As you can see depending on what field is null a specific custom exception is thrown with a custom message.

So, I would like to have something like this:

```
assertNotEquals(call, null, new CallerErrorException(new CallerError("", "incorrect caller")));
assertNotEquals(person, null, new PersonErrorException(new CustomerError("", "incorrect caller")));
assertNotEquals(module , null, new ModuleErrorException(new ModuleError("", "incorrect caller")));
```

Is there a built-in feature that allows me to do this?

I know that assertEquals generate an assertionError but I'd need to generate my custom exception.

Comment: Are you talking about `assertNotEquals` because you are writing unit tests?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight good observation. No, I'm not writing unit tests it's  for a backend entry point with a big amount of parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your own function:

```
public static <T extends Throwable> void throwIfNotEqual(Object o1, Object o2, T exception) throws T {
    if (o1 != o2) {
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

#### Update

If this approach is combined with [the approach of @dasblinkenlight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24196058/2991525) you have the benefit of creating the exception only if it's needed and you still be more precise than "throws Exception". The signature would then be:

```
static <T extends Throwable> void checkNull(Object val, Class<T> exClass, Class innerClass, String arg1, String arg2)
    throws T, ReflectiveOperationException
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing built in that would work for this, but you can certainly write your own:

```
static void checkNull(Object val, Class exClass, Class innerClass, String arg1, String arg2)
    throws Exception {
    if (val != null) {
        return;
    }
    Object inner = innerClass
        .getDeclaredConstructor(String.class, String.class)
        .newInstance(arg1, arg2);
    throw (Exception)exClass
        .getDeclaredConstructor(innerClass) // This may need to be changed 
        .newInstance(inner);
}
```

The above code uses reflection to build the exception object as needed. You may have to change the type that you pass to the constructor of the exception object if it takes a superclass of the inner error object to match the correct type.

Now you can write your code as follows:

```
checkNull(caller, CallerErrorException.class, CallerError.class, "", "incorrect caller");
checkNull(person, PersonErrorException.class, PersonError.class, "", "incorrect person");
```

This approach lets you avoid creating the exception object in cases when you do not need to throw it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple implementation using JAVA 8

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> inputs = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
        AssertUtils.check(inputs, input -> inputs.contains(5), new RuntimeException("Element 5 doesn't exist"));

        String nullString = null;
        AssertUtils.check(nullString, Objects::nonNull, new RuntimeException("Input is null"));
    }

}

/**
 * Assert to throw Custom exceptions rather than default IllegalArgumentException by {@link
 * org.springframework.util.Assert}. 
 * Usage:
 * AssertUtil.check(input, predicate, customException)
 * Example:
 * List<Integer> inputs = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4);
        AssertUtils.check(inputs, input -> inputs.contains(5), new RuntimeException("Element 5 doesn't exist"));
 * @param <T>
 */
class AssertUtils<T> {

    public static <T> void check(T input, Predicate<T> predicate, RuntimeException runtimeException) {
        if (!predicate.test(input)) {
            throw runtimeException;
        }
    }
}
```